# Does AirFlow support custom calendar or Flexi calendar?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have one requirement, in my application every month TWS job get trigger on different dates. For example,  Monthly job in Jan will run on 10th and in Feb it will run on 15th and in march on 20th ....Is there any way to implement this in AirFlow ? Not sure if we can do this using Crons, since day(dd) is different in each month. Does AirFlow support custom calendar ?

Not sure if we can do this using Crons, since day(dd) is different in each month

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to use `BranchOperator` that will call your Python function with the business logic:

```
dag = DAG(....) # trigger daily

def define_datetime(context):
  # here your logic to find the route to follow, depending on the execution time
  # you should find this date in context['execution_date']
  return "execute" if date_is_expected() else "pass"

with dag:
  branch = BranchPythonOperator(
    ...
  )

  pass = DummyOperator(task_id='pass',...)

  execute = PythonOperator(task_id='execute'...) # or any operator that will execute the job

  branch >> [pass, execute]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bartosz25. I will try using above code. I have one more requirement, I want to trigger a Dag on Tuesday after 3rd Saturday of every month. Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Same here. You can add a CRON schedule on Tuesday and in the router check whether the execution time is after the 3rd Saturday of the month.

Comment: Thanks bartosz25. I think it is BranchPythonOperator, it worked fine.

Comment: Indeed, it's this one. I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @Afz Abd - did you manage to implement the code? My answer helped you?

Comment: I have a question related to pausing a task id. Can you please help me on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096685/how-to-pause-a-task-in-airflow

Comment: Hi, before that, could you please check this documentation page about asking questions on StackOverflow and decide whether the answers for all your questions are useful or not? --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers